# How many optical and acoustical branches are in a primitive cell?

Tags: solid-state-physics, crystals, phonons, dispersion

I am reading Introduction to Solid-State Physics (by Kittel) and I don't understand how he counts the optical and acoustical branches in a primitive cell.

It says that if there are $p$ atoms in a primitive cell then we have $3p$ branches, 3 acoustical branches and $3p-3$ optical branches.

I understand the physical difference of an optical and acoustical branche. But I don't understand:

1. How do you know there are $3p$ branches?
2. How do you know only $3$ ($3p-3$) are acoustical (optical)?

Answer (score 7):

**TL;DR:** We have $3p$ branches in total, corresponding to $3p$ independent modes of vibration. We have $3$ acoustic branches, because we are in $3d$ space, ***AND***, Because we are dealing with an *Elastic Medium*, and not a *Fluid*.

**Long version:** The following discussion is based on $\S69$, *Statistical Physics ; Part 1 (3ed)* , Landau. The discussion mirrors Kittel's treatment (but is more lucid, in my opinion) :

Let us say we have $p$  (assume for simplicity, identical) atoms per unit cell on a lattice. Each primitive cell is labelled by $n$ = $(n_1,n_2,n_3)$ (or, $r_n =n_i a_i$ , where $a_i$ are the lattice vectors) . We are looking for *modes of Elastic vibration* of this system. We will denote the displacement of the $i^{th}$ atom in the $n^{th}$ primitive cell as $u_{i}(n)$.

The solid is elastic, so the equations of motions for the displacements of the atoms should look like a system of coupled oscillators :

$\ddot{u_{i}}(n)= -\sum_{j,m}\Lambda_{ij}(n,m)u_j(m)$, where the $\Lambda$'s are some positive definite "spring constants". It is easy to motivate from the (discrete) translation symmetry of the lattice that $\Lambda(n,m) = \Lambda(n-m)$.

We are looking for *plane-wave solutions* of the form $u_i(n) = e_i(k)e^{i(k.r_n - \omega t)}$ for some wave-vector $k$ , where $e_i(k)$ is the *"Polarization vector"* corresponding to the given mode of vibration. Note that the polarization has an index $i$ ; in general, we are allowed independent vibrations for the $p$ atoms in the primitive cell.

Plugging into the E.O.M. above, we obtain :

$-\omega^2e_i(k) = -\sum_{j,m}\Lambda_{ij}(n-m)e^{ik.(r_m-r_n)}e_j(k) = -\sum_j \Lambda_{ij}(k)e_j(k)$,

where $\Lambda_{ij}(k) \equiv \sum_m \Lambda_{ij}(m) e^{-ir_m.k}$

The polarization vectors are themselves $3d$ vectors. We can make this explicit, by including another index $\alpha , \beta = 1,2,3$. Finally, we can write the above equation in the form of an eigenvalue equation:

$\sum_{(j,\beta)}[\Lambda_{(i\alpha)(j\beta)} (k)-\omega^2 \delta_{ij} \delta_{\alpha\beta}]e_{j\beta}(k) = 0$

The eigenvalues are solutions of $det|\Lambda_{(i\alpha)(j\beta)} (k)-\omega^2 \delta_{ij} \delta_{\alpha\beta}| = 0$. We can see that for any $k$, the $\Lambda$'s are $3p \times 3p$ matrices. Hence, **for any $k$, there are $3p$ distinct solutions for $\omega(k)$.** These $3p$ distinct solutions correspond to the $3p$ ***distinct branches***

Now, any $3d$ elastic material is known to have $3$ modes of vibration, which have the property that $\omega(k) \to 0$ as $k \to 0$. These are the so called ***acoustic modes***. These represent the propagation of ***Sound*** in the elastic medium, which are *mechanical waves* observed *macroscopically* (ie, in the long wavelength, slow frequency limit). Naturally, these are the modes for which there is *no relative motion* between the p-atoms in a single unit cell, ie., the entire primitive cell undergoes center of mass displacement (that is, for these modes, $e_i$ is independent of $i$).

This is why $\omega(k) \to 0$ as $k \to 0$ : For the acoustic modes, The $k \to 0$ limit corresponds to a parallel displacement of the entire lattice ; there is obviously no restoring forces in this case, and hence, $\omega(k) \to 0$.

**Why are there $3$ acoustic modes?** It can be seen that this is because for a given $k$, there are $3$ distinct directions for $e$ (remembering that for acoustic modes, there is no $i$ dependence) : Two in the plane $\perp$ $k$  ie.  , $e.k = 0$ , and the remainder along $k$ ; these are what Kittel calls the TA and  LA branches respectively (pg $97$).

$NOTE$ that apart from the $3-$ dimensionality of space, the elasticity of the medium is also a crucial ingredient in how many modes of sound we have. The two transverse modes of sound represent *shear* waves, whereas the remaining one is the familiar Longitudinal sound. In contrast, (normal) ***Fluids*** cannot support shear waves. That is why they have only one mode of sound per $k$.

Answer (score 3):

For a primitive cell with p atoms in 3d space, there are 3p degrees of freedom, say x, y, and z for each of the p atoms. This leads to 3p total harmonic modes and hence there are a total of 3p branches.

For an acoustic mode, the atoms within the primitive cell need to move exactly in phase, giving a dispersion relation where the frequency vanishes linearly with k in the long-wavelength limit. This can happen in 3 ways, where all the atoms in the lattice move in phase along x, y or z directions (or equivalently along any 3 orthogonal directions). Hence, there are 3 acoustic modes.

In all the remaining modes, all atoms within the primitive cell will not move in phase, giving 3p-3 optical modes.

Quoting Ashcroft-Mermin, "An acoustic mode is one in which all ions within a primitive cell move essentially in phase, as a unit, and the dynamics are dominated by the interaction between cells; an optical mode, on the other hand, is one in which the ions within each primitive cell are executing what is essentially a molecular vibratory mode, which is broadened put into a band of frequencies by virtue of the intercellular interactions".